# Is the predicate of std::condition_variable executed under lock?

Tags: c++, c++11

As condition variable could check whether given predicate is true or not, and return only if it is true (like below snippet), is the predicate running inside the protection of lock included in the condition variable (`mutex m` in below snippet)?

```
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex m;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk;

cv.wait(lk, []{/*predicate*/});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call `cv.wait(lk, p)` is defined by [thread.condition.condvar] to be equivalent to:

```
while (!p())
    cv.wait(lk);
```

Moreover, the precondition for `wait` is that the calling thread holds the lock. Therefore, yes indeed, the predicate check happens under the lock.

Anything other than this behaviour wouldn't make a lot of sense, since otherwise checking the predicate would produce a data race unless you would provide a *separate* synchronisation mechanism for the predicate.

Answer (score 2):

The version of `wait()` that takes a predicate is equivalent to:

```
while (!pred())
    wait(lock);
```

Hence, the predicate is checked outside the `wait(lock)` call (and the lock is unlocked only inside that call), meaning that the lock is locked when the predicate is checked.